# IS my database normalized?

Tags: database-design

many user can create many Events. And users can send request to owner to participate in that event(as candidate, voter or both). When it's a candidate request then additional details are stored in candidate details table.

```
User(u_id pk, username, password)

Event(e_id pk,u_id,e_name,e_date)
```

`UserRequestPool(urp_id pk,u_id,e_id,request_type)`#adding 2 entries if request type is both

```
CandidateDetails(id pk,u_id,e_id,candidate_image,candidate_promises)
```

`Ballot(u_id,e_id,flag)` #to ensure duplicate voting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the user request pool id in the candidate details instead of the event id and user id:

```
CandidateDetails (id pk, urp_id, candidate_image, candidate_promises)
```

Same for the ballot table:

```
Ballot (urp_id, flag)
```

You might want to store the request types in a table:

```
UserRequestPool (urp_id pk, u_id, e_id, r_id)

RequestType (r_id, request_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Candidate can be a User? you wouldn't want to rule it out and you can then prevent them up voting their own events.
User involvement context should be independent of the subject name( candidate_details is a bad choice and may limit future enhancements to the database), keep your semantics clean - this is just a stylistic recommendation but it helps all round, the user's participation in events should be recorded in link tables
user_vote (u_id,e_id,vote)
user_participant (u_id,e_id,status(accepted,denied))

Answer (score 0):

istead of duplicated entries in userrequestpool, you may define one more request_type or r_id that corresponds to both